# openlink virtuoso installation ./config throwing error

Tags: macos, installation, openssl, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I'm trying to install virtuoso's stable/7 branch manually from https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource. However, when I run ./configure, I get this error message after about 30 seconds:

checking OpenSSL version... configure: error: OpenSSL version 0.9.8e or greater is required.

The thing is, I do have OpenSSL. When I type openssl version -a in my terminal, I get this output:

benjhatch@benjamins-mbp virtuoso-opensource-stable-7 % openssl version -a

LibreSSL 2.8.3

built on: date not available

platform: information not available

options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)

compiler: information not available

OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"

Why is it saying I need an openssl version of 0.9.8e or greater? Is there any way to fix this?
This is on a Mac that runs MacOS Catalina version 10.15.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues has been resolved in the default Virtuoso open source develop/7 branch from:

```
https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/develop/7
```

which now supports LibreSSL  which is what is shipped as the only SSL library available for the the latest macOS versions ...